# hosts file not working as expected in OS X

Tags: macos, apache, xampp, hosts

OS: OS X 10.6.8

Running Xampp

I'm having trouble with my hosts file, and can't figure out the problem.

Hosts file

```
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1   localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
fe80::1%lo0 localhost
127.0.0.1 proj.dev
::1 proj.dev
```

Vhosts in Xampp

```
NameVirtualHost *:80


<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs"
    ServerName localhost
  <Directory "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs">
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/Users/davey/Dropbox/proj"
    ServerName amas.dev
  <Directory "/Users/davey/Dropbox/proj">
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Despite numerous restarts and flushing of the cache using Temrinal, I can't get this to work.
In Terminal, pinging gets me this result:

```
rafter:~ davey$ ping proj.dev
PING amas.dev (127.0.0.1): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.053 ms
*snip*
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=7 ttl=64 time=0.116 ms
^C
--- amas.dev ping statistics ---
8 packets transmitted, 8 packets received, 0.0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 0.053/0.109/0.121/0.021 ms
```

Yet the following command goes like this:

```
rafter:~ davey$ host proj.dev
Host proj.dev not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)
```

Complete dead end, don't know what to do. Any ideas?

I've been editing the files variously using Smultron, pico and nano.
Tomcat is installed, but not running.

EDIT

Ok, I think I may have narrowed it down.
In terminal I get the following:

```
rafter:~ davey$ host -v amas.dev
Trying "amas.dev"
Received 101 bytes from 134.226.32.57#53 in 0 ms
Trying "amas.dev.scss.tcd.ie"
Host amas.dev not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)
Received 91 bytes from 134.226.32.57#53 in 1 ms
```

That IP number is the proxy on the network. Does that make a difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `host` command is a DNS diagnostic tool that.  It *only* queries DNS and never references the local `hosts` file.  Commands that call `gethostbyname()` or similar functions *do* reference local naming services, which may include the local `hosts` file.

The fact that system commands like `ping` are getting the correct ip address indicates that things are configured correctly.

[This document](http://decoding.wordpress.com/2009/04/06/how-to-edit-the-hosts-file-in-mac-os-x-leopard/) suggests you may need to flush your DNS cache if the system has previously cached a lookup for the hostname with an address different from what you have added to the local hosts file.

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out - I was also running the host command to try validate that the /etc/hosts file was working correctly. Using the ping command showed that the hosts file was being used correctly.